# How can i use kendo UI with oracle AdF?

Tags: kendo-ui, oracle-adf

can i use kendo UI as front end for our web based application and

oracle adf as back end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. (since it's just JS)

Comment: thanks, i easked kindo directly and they confirm that "Kendo UI is a client library that is independent from the back-end and you can use Oracle ADF on the back-end as well."